# c++11 lambda high-order function wrapper recursive error

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

function<int(int)> wrapper(function<void(int)> f)
{
    auto ff = [&](int a) {
        cout << "in wrapper " << a << endl;
        f(a);
        return 1;
    };
    return ff;
}

int main()
{
    auto fa = wrapper([](int a){
        cout << "in fa " << a << endl;
    });
    fa(999);
    wrapper([&fa](int b){
        cout << "in anon " << b << endl;
        fa(998);
    })(997);
}
```

The above code will print

```
in wrapper 999
in fa 999
in wrapper 997
in anon 997
in wrapper 998                                                                                                                                                  
in anon 998                                                                                                                                                     
in wrapper 998                                                                                                                                                  
in anon 998                                                                                                                                                     
in wrapper 998                                                                                                                                                  
in anon 998                                                                                                                                                     
in wrapper 998                                                                                                                                                  
in anon 998                                                                                                                                                     
in wrapper 998                                                                                                                                                  
in anon 998                                                                                                                                                     
in wrapper 998                                                                                                                                                  
in anon 998                                                                                                                                                     
..........
```

until Segmentation fault.

I write the same code in javascript

```
function  wrapper(f)
{
    var ff = function(a) {
        console.log("in wrapper %s", a);
        f(a);
        return 1;
    };
    return ff;
}

(function ()
{
    var fa = wrapper(function(a){
        console.log("in fa %s", a);
    });
    fa(999);
    wrapper(function(b){
        console.log("in anon %s", b);
        fa(998);
    })(997);
})();
```

It will print

```
in wrapper 999
in fa 999
in wrapper 997
in anon 997
in wrapper 998
in fa 998
```

What's with the c++ lambda code?
I tried the g++-5.0 and g++4.9 compiler. All ended up with this error.

Answer (score 4):

`ff` captures `f` by reference, but `f` is local to `wrapper`. When you return `ff`, that reference becomes dangling, and undefined behaviour is triggered upon calling `ff`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'm really sorry, but this code hurts my brain :(

Comment: But how can finish the job. I change the function<int(int)> wrapper(function<void(int)> f) to function<int(int)> wrapper(function<void(int)>& f). But the compiler says  error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::function<void(int)>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::function<void(int)
>’

Comment: I figured it out myself. Change the auto ff = [&](int a) to auto ff = [=](int a) .